# File upload from form not woking in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

File upload is not working I am stuck. I don't know how to append formdata() of file and state value in `Values` and pass it to api as form-data

```js
  const [Values, setValues] = useState({});
  const [image, setImage] = useState();

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    setValues({ ...Values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
const onChange = (e) => {
    // let files = files;
    setValues({ ...Values, [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0] });
  };


  const submitValue = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
   

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
        "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    };
    axios
      .patch("profile-update/", Values, config)
      .then(() => {
        alert("updated data");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
      });

    console.log(allValues);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    };

    axios.get("customer-profile/", config).then((res) => {
      //  console.log(res.data.details);
      setdata(res.data.customer);
      setdetails(res.data.details);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div style={styles.wrapper}>
                <form className="medical-edit-form" style={styles.form}>
          
          <small style={styles.filehelp1}>
            <span style={styles.fileP1}>
              allergic reaction?
            </span>
            <input
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="allergic_reaction"
              style={styles.date}
              type="text"
              defaultValue={details.allergic_reaction}
            
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.datehelp}>
            Surgery?
            <input
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="surgery"
              style={styles.date}
              type="text"
              defaultValue={details.surgery}
             
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.datehelp}>
             Menstruation Period 
            <input
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="Menstruation"
              style={styles.date}
              type="number"
              defaultValue={details.Menstruation}
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.datehelp}>
            Menstruation
            <input
              name="Menstruation"
              onChange={changeHandler}
              defaultValue={details.Menstruation_date}
              style={styles.date}
              type="date"
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.datehelp}>
            Heridity?
            <input
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="hereditory"
              style={styles.date}
              defaultValue={details.hereditory}
              type="text"
             
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.filehelp1}>
            <span style={styles.fileP1}>
              Gynacology
              Specify.
            </span>
            <input
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="gynacology"
              style={styles.date}
              type="text"
              defaultValue={details.gynacology}
             
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.filehelp1}>
            <span style={styles.fileP1}>
               pregnent?
            </span>
            <input
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="pregnant"
              style={styles.date}
              type="text"
              defaultValue={pregnant}
            
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.datehelp}>
            visit doctor?
            <input
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="doctor_final_visit"
              style={styles.date}
              defaultValue={details.doctor_final_visit}
              type="date"
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.filehelp}>
            <span style={styles.fileP}>
              Upload image
            </span>
            <input name="prescription" onChange={onChange} type="file" />
          </small>
          <div>
            <input
              onClick={submitValue}
              style={styles.ebtn}
              type="submit"
              value="update"
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

with out the file upload the form works fine I also want to add the file upload to this code so I can upload the file also.

Comment: The first error is that `Image` is already a constructor declared in the global namespace of JavaScript. So your state name has to start with a small 'i'

Comment: `axios.patch()` only accept three arguments, you are passing four

Comment: @Phil i am trying to append 2 of those arugments but i dont know how ,i know values and formdata has to be appended before passing it to the api

Comment: If you are saying that your form is correctly uploading without the file then you need to check the input element and when you are setting the state just change from e.target.value to e.target.files[0]

Comment: @MDMNauman can u share a example it would be very helpfull

Comment: @MDMNauman i have updated my question as u asked but upload not working of file

Comment: @meon I'm not able to understand from where setAllValues() function came? whether you have made a typo?

Comment: @MDMNauman   oh i am sorry   setAllValues() is  setValues

Comment: `setValues({ ...allValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0] });` one more typo in spreading the values and you wrote `...allValues`

Comment: Now in the submit handler you have to use form data API like this `const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('File', imageState) ` the image state will be the file you got from input

Comment: i dont understant can u edit my questoion and post it as an answer it will be helpfull @MDMNauman

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this will work or not as I'm not able to test writing as per assumption.

```
  const [Values, setValues] = useState({});
  const [image, setImage] = useState();

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    setValues({ ...Values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

const FileHandler = (e) => {
    // let files = files;
    setImage(e.target.files[0]);
  };



  const submitValue = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

   const formData = new FormData(); 
   formData.append('Image', image);
   setValues({...Values, formData})

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
        "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    };
    axios
      .patch("profile-update/", Values, config)
      .then(() => {
        alert("updated data");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
      });

    
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    };

    axios.get("customer-profile/", config).then((res) => {
      //  console.log(res.data.details);
      setdata(res.data.customer);
      setdetails(res.data.details);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div style={styles.wrapper}>
                <form className="medical-edit-form" style={styles.form}>
          
          <small style={styles.filehelp1}>
            <span style={styles.fileP1}>
              allergic reaction?
            </span>
            <input
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="allergic_reaction"
              style={styles.date}
              type="text"
              defaultValue={details.allergic_reaction}
            
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.datehelp}>
            Surgery?
            <input
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="surgery"
              style={styles.date}
              type="text"
              defaultValue={details.surgery}
             
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.datehelp}>
             Menstruation Period 
            <input
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="Menstruation"
              style={styles.date}
              type="number"
              defaultValue={details.Menstruation}
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.datehelp}>
            Menstruation
            <input
              name="Menstruation"
              onChange={changeHandler}
              defaultValue={details.Menstruation_date}
              style={styles.date}
              type="date"
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.datehelp}>
            Heridity?
            <input
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="hereditory"
              style={styles.date}
              defaultValue={details.hereditory}
              type="text"
             
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.filehelp1}>
            <span style={styles.fileP1}>
              Gynacology
              Specify.
            </span>
            <input
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="gynacology"
              style={styles.date}
              type="text"
              defaultValue={details.gynacology}
             
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.filehelp1}>
            <span style={styles.fileP1}>
               pregnent?
            </span>
            <input
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="pregnant"
              style={styles.date}
              type="text"
              defaultValue={pregnant}
            
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.datehelp}>
            visit doctor?
            <input
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="doctor_final_visit"
              style={styles.date}
              defaultValue={details.doctor_final_visit}
              type="date"
            />
          </small>
          <small style={styles.filehelp}>
            <span style={styles.fileP}>
              Upload image
            </span>
            <input name="prescription" onChange={FileHandler} type="file" />
          </small>
          <div>
            <input
              onClick={submitValue}
              style={styles.ebtn}
              type="submit"
              value="update"
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: i tryed as ur answer but i am getting a error when i click submit `detail: "Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"`  @MD M Nauman

Comment: `"Content-type": "multipart/form-data`", i think the error is here